# how to build Proper ListTIle with image

Tags: flutter, dart

i always build ListTile like this, the problem is the upper text 'Bluckcurrent' and the bottom text 'STOCK: 10' is not in the same line with the end of image. I want it to match the image height automatically. Sorry for my bad explanation, if you need more information please tell me i will update the question.

[image]

```
Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 8, 16, 8),
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: 90,
                    height: 100,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Constants.blueLightColor.withOpacity(0.2),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                    ),
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.image_outlined,
                      size: 42,
                      color: Constants.blueLightColor,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 10),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'BLACKCURRENT MOUNT TEA',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: Constants.bold,
                          ),
                          maxLines: 2,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '250ml',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            height: 1.4,
                            fontSize: 12,
                            color: Constants.greyColor,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Rp. 8.000',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            height: 1.7,
                            fontWeight: Constants.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'STOCK : 10',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            height: 1.7,
                            fontWeight: Constants.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 16),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a sizedBox with specific height wrapping the row widget and the let the image fetch its width. And in the Column of the Text widgets add a spacer where you wish to add extra space

```dart
SizedBox(
          height: 100,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Image.network(
                "https://www.bastiaanmulder.nl/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/dummy-image-portrait.jpg",
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 10,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 200,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "Some title here",
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    Text("Price: \$60"),
                    Spacer(),
                    Text(
                      "Stock : 10",
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

[image: preview]

Just to show it will align properly, increasing the height to 200

[image: preview2]

Comment: I think this answer is the most suitable for me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this.

since image height is dynamic, then it will align vertically with all the column children on the right side

```
Card(
  child: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
    width: double.infinity,
    child: Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned(
            child: SizedBox(
// no need to set height 
// SizedBox will strech following widget on the right
              width: 50, 
              child: Image.network(
                'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
                fit: BoxFit.cover, // you can modified as you need
              ),
            ),
            top: 0, // 
            left: 0,
            bottom: 0), // 
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 60),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                'WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 18,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Text("lorem ipsum"),
              SizedBox(
                height:5,
              ),
              Text("lorem ipsum"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try: set Container height 100

```
child: Container(
          height: 100,
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 8, 16, 8),...
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using MainAxisSize.min ?

It will fix column height to children height.

```dart
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  children: [
    ...
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **IntrinsicHeight** widget to wrap your Row.

> IntrinsicHeight(child: Row())

[image]